# C# Azure DevOps Git: Unable to push new directories

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops

I'm trying to work with Azure DevOps Git API for C# .Net, and for the most part I've figured it out. However I'm having issues with pushing a new directory to the repository.

Below is the relevant code snippets I have so far;

**Create the Commit**

```
        GitCommitRef commit = new GitCommitRef()
        {
            Comment = "Add a sample file",
            Changes = new GitChange[]
            {
                new GitChange()
                {
                    ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Add,
                    Item = new GitItem() { Path = "/TESTFOLDER", GitObjectType = GitObjectType.Tree, IsFolder = true },
                    NewContent = null
                    //NewContent = new ItemContent()
                    //{
                    //    Content = Utilities.ReadFile(fileNamePath),
                    //    ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText
                    //}
                 },

                new GitChange()
                {
                    ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Add,
                    Item = new GitItem() {Path = "/TESTFOLDER/" + fileName, GitObjectType = GitObjectType.Blob, IsFolder = false },
                    NewContent = new ItemContent()
                    {
                        Content = Utilities.ReadFile(fileNamePath),
                        ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText
                    }

                }
```

**Create the Push**

```
        GitPush toPush = new GitPush()
        {
            RefUpdates = new GitRefUpdate[] { newBranch },
            Commits = new GitCommitRef[] { commit }
        };

        // Create the push with the new branch and commit
        GitPush push = gitClient.CreatePushAsync(toPush, repo.Id).Result;
```

WHen it executes the Push with that commit, it errors saying "The parameters supplied are not valid. Parameter name: newPush".

I have had trouble finding anything in the documentation that could help me figure out how to place the "fileName" file, inside a directory created at the same time?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but I know Git doesn't typically think in terms of "directories" as source control artifacts. For example, you can't create an empty directory in git. Have you tried simply pushing your new file, without trying to add the folder?

Comment: That could work, but I've not figured out how to commit a file. Currently I'm copying the text in the files and writing it into the commit content as a string :/  The sample code they provide for Pushes doesn't go into much more detail than creating a blank file :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be caused by the `GitChange` object for the `TESTFOLDER` directory in `GitChanges`.

You donot need to specify a new `GitChange` object for the `TESTFOLDER` directory. As @StriplingWarrior commented empty directory is not allowed in git.

You can just specify a new `GitChange` object for the file only. If the directory which the file resides doesnot exist. It will be automatically created.

See below:

```
GitCommitRef commit = new GitCommitRef()
        {
            Comment = "Add a sample file",
            Changes = new GitChange[]
            {
                new GitChange()
                {
                    ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Add,
                    Item = new GitItem() {Path = "/TESTFOLDER/" + fileName, GitObjectType = GitObjectType.Blob, IsFolder = false },
                    NewContent = new ItemContent()
                    {
                        Content = Utilities.ReadFile(fileNamePath),
                        ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText
                    }

                }
```

See below screen from my test: The directory was automatically created.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately when I do this it just places it in the root of the branch usually saying "Directory 'TESTFOLDER' could not be found or I don't have permission etc). To clarify, "ReadFile()" is currently just reading a text file and converting the text into a string. Is there a way to just upload the entire file as an object (IE if there were DLLs to be pushed also etc)

Comment: .....It worked, but this is what I had to begin with, and it tried to create a file called "/TESTFOLDER/{filename}"