# Updating git submodule through ADO libraries

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, libgit2sharp

I am currently working on a git repo which has some git submodules. I am trying to write a C# console app which would update the commit the submodule points to.

Here's what I have tried so far.

1. Create a branch using [GitRefUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitrefupdate?view=azure-devops-dotnet) class

```
            // Create a new branch for PR
            GitRefUpdate newBranch = new GitRefUpdate
            {
                Name = $"refs/heads/{branchName}",
                OldObjectId = branchRef.ObjectId,
                IsLocked = false,
                RepositoryId = _repository.Id
            };
```

2. Create [GitItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gititem?view=azure-devops-dotnet) to update

```
            GitItem commitChangeItem = new GitItem()
            {
                GitObjectType = GitObjectType.Commit,
                ObjectId = TargetCommit,
                OriginalObjectId = commitItem.ObjectId, //commitItem is the GitItem representing current version of the commit
                Path = "path/to/the/commit/file"
            };
```

3. Create a [GitChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitchange?view=azure-devops-dotnet) object

```
            GitChange commitChange = new GitChange()
            {
                ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Edit,
                Item = commitChangeItem,
                OriginalPath = commitItem.Path
            };
```

4. Create a [GitCommitRef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitcommitref?view=azure-devops-dotnet) and [GitPush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitpush?view=azure-devops-dotnet) object

```
            var changeCounts = new ChangeCountDictionary();
            changeCounts.Add(VersionControlChangeType.Edit, 1);
            var commit = new GitCommitRef
            {
                Comment = commitMessage,
                Changes = gitChanges,
                ChangeCounts = changeCounts 
            };

            var push = new GitPush
            {
                RefUpdates = new[] { newBranch },
                Commits = new[] { commit },
                Repository = _repository,
                
            };
```

5. Push the push object using [GitHttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.githttpclient?view=azure-devops-dotnet) object

```
pushResult = await _gitHttpClient.CreatePushAsync(push, project:"Project_Name", _repository.Id);
```

However, when I follow these steps it tells me that the parameters supplied to the push are not valid.[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozqak.png)

Does any one know what parameters I need to create this push.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample code on how to use Git Push submodule

```
_git push_ [--all | --mirror | --tags] [--follow-tags] [--atomic] [-n | --dry-run] [--receive-pack=<git-receive-pack>]
       [--repo=<repository>] [-f | --force] [-d | --delete] [--prune] [-v | --verbose]
       [-u | --set-upstream] [-o <string> | --push-option=<string>]
       [--[no-]signed|--signed=(true|false|if-asked)]
       [--force-with-lease[=<refname>[:<expect>]] [--force-if-includes]]
       [--no-verify] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]
```

For further information follow [Git Push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) Documentation.
Also check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473021/c-sharp-azure-devops-git-unable-to-push-new-directories) with related information.